# Seguridad en peticiones http de AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

Estoy realizando peticiones http a una ruta de laravel, pero necesito que el resultado de la peticion no se muestre al acceder a la ruta por ejemplo si obtengo los usuarios con la ruta /getUsers se muestran los datos de la siguiente manera

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"Usuario1",
   "email":"usuario1@ejemplo.com",
   "facebook_id":null,
   "created_at":"2018-11-16 10:19:41",
   "updated_at":"2018-11-16 10:19:41"
}
```

¿Como podria asegurar que no se muestren los datos al acceder a la ruta /getUser?

He intentado con `if(!$request->ajax())return redirect('/');` y al acceder a la ruta me redirecciona pero desde la vista no muetsra nada.

Comment: No queda nada claro lo que quieres hacer ¿Dónde se ven esos datos? ¿A quién quieres ocultar esa información?

Comment: Los datos se ven cuando accedo a la ruta http://127.0.0.1:8000/getUser lo que quiero es ocultarlos a la vista de quien logre acceder a esa ruta.